# Find difference of 2 numbers in C

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int A,B,diff;
    
    printf("Enter the first number :");
    scanf("%d",&A);
    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%d",&B);
    
    diff = B-A;
    
    printf("%d",diff);
    
}
```

I was getting an error in my eLab online compiler.
Error message **command failed: ./a.out <input.txt**

Comment: where's your int main()?

Comment: this program is missing includes

Comment: You mean #include <stdio.h>?

Comment: At the en of your main(), put "return 0;" to indicate that the program run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this? You missed the Header `#include <stdio.h>` which is a must in your program or else it won't work. On top of that, please include `return 0` at the end of the program which is right before the close brace of `main()`.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int A,B,diff;

printf("Enter the first number :");
scanf("%d",&A);
printf("Enter the second number : ");
scanf("%d",&B);

diff = B-A;

printf("%d",diff);

return 0

}
```

Comment: Thanks I have included main and return 0. It's working fine. Can you tell me what is the use of this ```return 0```

Comment: The OS expects main to return a value to know if the program succeeded or not.  0 is success, non-zero is failure.  There are defined macros to handle these values as well.

Comment: It's similar to System.exit(0) in Java. So when there is a successful program that is being executed, the system should return a exit status to imply if it's workable or not

Comment: @JustwantNingthoujam Please tick this as your answer since your program is working once I've posted full solution of it